# Push service ionic 2

Tags: ionic-framework, push-notification, ionic2

I have follow this tutorial (https://devdactic.com/ionic-2-push-notifications/#disqus_thread)

I do not receive notification (status sent on ionic.io) on physical iOS Device with TestFlight. (But the token is generated).

app.component.ts and app.module.ts `file`: https://pastebin.com/HB97KdWL

I have try official tutorial but same problem..

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Test APNS using  [pushtry](http://pushtry.com/). Check if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, there are a bunch of things that could go wrong, especially with ios. Here are some things to look at:

1. **Managing the certificates for the APNS can be rough.**  If you have
   access to an android device, start there since it's a little more
   straightforward to get notifications up and running.
2. Since you're using apps.ionic.io, you have the advantage of checking
   to see if you have a push token assigned to a user.  (I'm assuming
   that you're using auth?) In the Auth tab, select the
   user->View->check the push tab to see the token. Also, use the push
   service to send a generic push notification to the users to see if
   it arrives.
   [image]
3. If you have a problem with ios, there's a strong likelihood that
   there's something wrong with the certificates... so check for
   another tutorial on that.  I'd recommend using the Ionic Cloud Services website instead of Devdactics since Ionic is more in-depth. You can find it here: https://docs.ionic.io/services/push/#prerequisites
4. Make sure that the "Background Notifications" and "Push
   Notifications are selected on the General tab in the Xcode project. 
   Since you're using Ionic, changing anything with 'cordova platform
   add ios' can overwrite it.  Make sure it looks like this: [![enter
   image description here][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjhYz.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjhYz.png)
5. This might be an oversight?...in your code, you have this:

   `const cloudSettings: CloudSettings = {
       'core': {
       'app_id': 'XXXXXX'  **<-- this should be a value. (not XXXXXX)**
        },
       'push': {
       'sender_id': 'XXXXX', **<-- this should be a value. (not XXXXXX)**
       'pluginConfig': {
         'ios': {
           'badge': true,
           'sound': true
          },
         'android': {
           'iconColor': '#ff0000'
          }
         }
        }
       };`

app_id is something that is covered in the tutorial that you sent. It's under the IOS certificate section. It says, "After going through the Push guide you need to have your App Id from the Identifier you created inside your Apple profile. Copy that ID and open your config.xml and add your ID:"  This is the same ID that you'll put in that section of code.

Unfortunately, there are a lot of things that can go wrong with the certificates. I would focus there since the errors that you get can be unannounced.